# SELECT 2 VALUES with different requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm wondering if it is possible to select 2 values in a single select statement that have different criteria. I know I can achieve above with subquery, just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Consider the following table:

```
UserId | CreatedDate
1      | 2018-01-21
2      | 2018-02-21
3      | 2018-03-21
4      | 2018-11-21
5      | 2018-11-21
```

I wish to select total number of users and also total number of users that joined this month. I can do it with two queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [Users]

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [Users] 
WHERE MONTH(CreatedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(CreatedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

However, can this be a single select as oppose to two queries?

EDIT: To clear confusion, I'm looking for 2 columns, not two rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(CreatedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(CreatedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM [Users];
```

Note:  `MONTH[CreatedDate]` makes no sense, so I replaced the square braces with parentheses.

Comment: Because the OP wanted two rows not two columns?  Other than that I have no idea

Comment: That is simply unfair @GordonLinoff

Comment: Maybe because somebody beat you to it? I'm not sure why else, seems like a good answer to me.

Comment: @Hogan . . . Not only does two columns make more sense to me, but the OP has clarified:  "EDIT: To clear confusion, I'm looking for 2 columns, not two rows.".

Comment: @Bojan and who beat Gordon to it??

Comment: I'm falling off my chair Gordon -- it was 2 mins where I had an upvote and you had a down vote.  Might be the first time.

Comment: @Sami Brad posted just before Gordon, at least on my screen and time stamps have same minute. Anyway, don't think it was copied and gave it an upvote as it gave me the answer i'm looking for.

Comment: @Bojan Oh really? re-check the time then.

Comment: @Sami both have same "11 minutes ago" is there a way to see better?

Comment: gordan was first -- you can hover mouse over to see zulu time.

Answer (score 3):

I beleive this will do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH[CreatedDate] = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(CreatedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SubCountWithCriteria
FROM [Users]
```

Comment: That is a clever way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

*(This gives you two rows, if you want two columns others have shown that solution using CASE)*

```
SELECT 'Total Users', COUNT(*) 
FROM [Users]

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total this month', COUNT(*) 
FROM [Users] 
WHERE MONTH(CreatedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(CreatedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```